# play video extension files on server

Tags: html, web-services, video

I would like for files with `.3gp` or `.mp4` to play in the browser when you type the url path instead of giving you the download option.

I want something like this http://www.html5videoplayer.net/videos/toystory.mp4

This is what i currently have: http://www.reelychat.com/img/1/profileVid/SampleVideo.3gp

I am using GoDaddy web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set content type for that file type in the .htaccess file.

Add this to your htaccess file:

AddType video/video/3gpp 3gp

Read this article for more info: https://uk.godaddy.com/help/configure-mime-types-375

Answer (score 0):

More than likely, you'll need to add the MIME type to your server configuration. A brief search brought up this result. [Configure MIME types](https://www.godaddy.com/help/configure-mime-types-375). Updated examples below:

### Linux Hosting

The .htaccess file should reside in the same directory as the designated files. The .htaccess entry has the following syntax:

```
AddType mime-type ext
```

Using the your file extension as an example, the .htaccess entry would be the following:

```
AddType video/mp4 mp4
AddType video/3gpp 3gpp 3gp
```

### Windows Hosting

The web.config file should be located in the root directory of a Web site. Using .mp4 and .mpv as examples, adding MIME types with IIS 7 looks like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".3gp" mimeType="video/3gpp" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".3gpp" mimeType="video/3gpp" />
    </staticContent>
  <system.webServer>
</configuration>
```